Strapi Google Oauth Internal Server Error
I am trying to set google authentication with my Strapi app. I have gone through the setup and added the necessary links as shown from the screenshots below. However when I hit the endpoint https://livespaces-prod.ue.r.appspot.com/api/connect/google from which I expect to got to the google logic page where the user can select their account, I get a response "Internal Server Error" with a status code 500. Is there anything I might be doing wrong in my setup below and how do I fix this
Client credentials page

App Registration

Strapi setup page

